# Efficiently calling multiple variants of the grep command

Tags: commands, grep

## The context

I commonly execute the following variants of the `grep` command

- `grep --color -RHIn ''` (search in the current working directory)
- `grep --color -RHIn --include='*.org' '' ~/repos/dotfiles/emacs` (search in all the Org files present in a directory that contains configurations of other Emacs users)
- `grep --color -RHIn --include='init.el' ~/repos/dotfiles/emacs`  (search in all `init.el` files located in the directory mentioned above)
- `grep --color -RHIn --include='*.org' --include='*.el' '' ~/repos/dotfiles/emacs` (search in all `.el` and `.org` files files located in the directory mentioned above)

Whenever I want to use one of thoose variants, I press `M-x grep` and manually type them.

I'm looking for ways which can help me avoid manually typing those variants whenever I want to execute any of those

## Additional context

I've tried the following

```
(let ((grep-command "grep --color -RHIn ''")) (call-interactively grep))
(let ((grep-command "grep --color -RHIn --include='*.org' '' ~/repos/dotfiles/emacs")) (call-interactively grep))
...
```

The problem with this is that `call-interactively` considers the global value of the variable `grep-command` instead of the one provided by `let`. If this worked, then I would only need to do

```
; Variant 1

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g 1")
                (let ((grep-command "grep --color -RHIn ''")) (call-interactively grep)))

; Variant 2

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g 2")
                (let ((grep-command "grep --color -RHIn --include='*.org' ''")) (call-interactively grep)))

(... more variants)
```

## The question

Do you know a better way to automate this so that I don't have to manually type any of the `grep` variants? Is there a package that would display something like a menu that would show a menu item with a description for each variant such that when an item is selected, `grep` is executed with the corresponding variant of the selected item?

If you don't have any idea, I would really appreciate if you could explain how I can make a command (`(call-interactively 'grep)`, in this scenario) to consider the value of a variable provided by `let`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The O.P. may be interested in the `hydra` library by Abo-Abo:

https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra

Here is a custom example that does not rely upon `hydra` to select from pre-defined choices.  The letter `c` at the beginning of the `interactive` statement is an interactive code:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html  There may be a better way to get a preferred default command line as the first choice in the minibuffer that does not involve let-binding `grep-host-defaults-alist` to `nil`, but this seems to work:

```lisp
;;; Needed so that `pick-a-grep' works correctly the first time it is tried;
;;; otherwise, the let-bound `grep-command' gets ignored the first time around.
(require 'grep)

(defun pick-a-grep (choice)
  "Choices for selecting from pre-defined `grep-command'."
  (interactive "c[3] is one too many. | [D]o you like eggs?")
  (cond
    ((eq choice ?3)
      (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
            (grep-command "grep --color -RHIn ''"))
        (call-interactively 'grep)))
    ((eq choice ?D)
      (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
            (grep-command "grep --color -RHIn --include='*.org' '' ~/repos/dotfiles/emacs"))
        (call-interactively 'grep)))
    (t
      (message "You did not select any of the expected choices."))))
```

Comment: +1 for the hydra recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the answer of @lawlist, you can accomplish this with the [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) package.

```
(require 'grep)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-. g")
                (defhydra hydra-grep-variants (:color blue)
"
_r_: Search recursively
_co_: Search configurations (*.org)
_ce_: Search configurations (*.el)
_cm_: Search configurations (*.org, *.el)
"
                   ("r" (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
                              (grep-command "grep --color -RHIn '' ."))
                          (call-interactively 'grep)))
                   ("co" (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
                               (grep-command "grep --color -RHIn --include='*.org' '' ~/SourceCode/dotfiles/emacs"))
                           (call-interactively 'grep)))
                   ("ce" (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
                               (grep-find-command (concat "find " path/configs " -type f -name '*.el' ! -path '*/elpa/*' -exec grep --color -HIn '' {} +")))
                           (call-interactively 'find-grep)))
                   ("cm" (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
                               (grep-find-command (concat "find " path/configs " -type f \\( -name '*.org' -o -name '*.el' \\) ! -path '*/elpa/*' -exec grep --color -HIn '' {} +")))
                           (call-interactively 'find-grep)))))
```

Just press `C-. C-g {key}` to choose a `grep` variant.